# Ember one-to-one not serializing foreign key for one side of relationship

Tags: ember.js

I have two things in a monogamous relationship. For the sake of their anonymity, we'll refer to them as a `User` and a `Profile`

**user.js**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    profile: DS.belongsTo('profile', { async: false }),
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**profile.js**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    user: DS.belongsTo('user', { async: true }),
    active: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

Users are attached at the hip with their profiles, so the profile is always sideloaded.

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 23,
        "name": "Homer Simpson",
        "profile": 42
    },
    "profiles": [
        {
            "id": 42,
            "active": true,
            "profile": 23
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, say a user gets into trouble with the local criminal scene and decides to change his name. And to fly under the radar, he also wants his profile to be deactivated.

```
let user = this.get('user'),
    profile = user.get('profile');

profile.get('user.id'); // 23

user.set('name', 'Mr. Thompson');
user.save().then(() => {
    profile.set('active', false);
    return profile.save();
});
```

The payload for `user.save` is fine...

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 23,
        "name": "Mr. Thompson",
        "profile": 42
    }
}
```

But for `profile.save`..?

```
{
    "profile": {
        "id": 42,
        "active": false,
        "user": null
    }
}
```

**Why, oh why, is the user being set to `null`**?

There are no custom serializers coming into play nor any changes to `.save`

- *Ember CLI: 1.13.10*
- *Ember Data: 1.13.15*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I was wrong. There *was* a custom serializer coming into play, but it wasn't for Profile it was for a User.

**serializers/user.js**

```
 extractAttributes: function(modelClass, resourceHash) {
    var rval = this._super(modelClass, resourceHash);
    // add profile as profileId
    rval.profileId = resourceHash.profile;
    return rval;
 }
```

This was done as part of how someone else was structuring relationships before we restructured them.

Removing this **User** customization now causes **Profile** to serialize properly, keeping its `userId` intact on saving.

Answer (score 0):

does schedule object has user model when you are doing schedule.save()??

also your model is it  schedule or Profile?

Comment: Totally my bad.. Not sure why I didn't just use the original model names, but I updated the question to remove the typos